# Android Facebook invites not working properly

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, android-simple-facebook, facebook-invite-friends

I am using **Simple Facebook**.
Unfortunately I **can't send invites with SimpleFacebook** so I am using **AppInviteDialog** to invite friends.

```
 public void openDialogInvite(final Activity activity) {
    String AppURl = "my FB url...";  //Generated from //fb developers

    String previewImageUrl = "urlImage...";

    sCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    if (AppInviteDialog.canShow()) {
        AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
                .setApplinkUrl(AppURl).setPreviewImageUrl(previewImageUrl)
                .build();

        AppInviteDialog appInviteDialog = new AppInviteDialog(activity);
        appInviteDialog.registerCallback(sCallbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<AppInviteDialog.Result>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(AppInviteDialog.Result result) {
                        Log.d("Invitation", "Invitation Sent Successfully");
                        System.out.println("test onSuccess");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        System.out.println("test  on cancel");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                        Log.d("Invitation", "Error Occured");
                        System.out.println("test Error"+e.getMessage());

                    }
                });

        appInviteDialog.show(content);
    }

}
```

The dialog open Facebook invite screens:

[The invite progress bar look like everything is ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUbwO.png)

**But**, i get no response in the dialog callback.

i thought the problem was my AppLink because in the folowing code, appLink is always null:

```
 SimpleFacebook.initialize(this);


    Uri targetUrl = AppLinks.getTargetUrlFromInboundIntent(ProfileActivity.this, getIntent());
    if (targetUrl != null) {
        Log.i("Activity", "App Link Target URL: " + targetUrl.toString());
    } else {


        AppLinkData.fetchDeferredAppLinkData(
                this,
                new AppLinkData.CompletionHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDeferredAppLinkDataFetched(AppLinkData appLinkData) {
                        //process applink data
                        Log.i("Activity", "App Link Target URL: " + appLinkData);

                    }
                });
    }
```

AppLink was always null, so i used "Quick Start for App Links Hosting API", and created the appLink manually and i send it in the dialog.

Why i don't get nothing on callback response? and Facebook users do not receive my invite?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. It used to work for me about two weeks ago when I tested it in a development branch. Now after deploying it last week, the invited user always has appLinkData null.

I made some further changes but even when I now checkout the revision that used to work, the appLinkData is null.

Sorry for writing this as an answer instead of a comment but I don't have enought reputation yet.

Answer (score 0):

Do you call `CallbackManager.onActivityResult()`?

In order to execute the `FacebookCallback` instance you have registered, add this to your Activity or Fragment:

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      sCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```